# Importing classes in python 3.2

Tags: python, class, import, directory-structure

In file foo.py I want to import class A from file main.py with the following folderStructur:

```
main.py
__init__.py
|-folder1
  __init__.py
  |-folder 2
    __init__.py
    foo.py
  |-folder 3
  ...
```

How does the import-line has to look like?
I tried things like

```
from ..main import A
```

but i just got

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: Why not `from main import A`? (If that's not correct, I'm sorry; we need a bit more information on where you're trying to run the code that needs to import `A`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error comes from how you're running the file - if you want to do that relative import, you need to run your foo program like this:

```
>>> import topfolder.folder1.folder2.foo
>>> foo.run()
```

(In other words, you need to be treating the package structure from which you are importing as an actual package.)